# Use BeautifulSoup to scraping images

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using code as below

```
import time
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 
import cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("http://ipcamera.userlocal.jp/photos/latest?camera_id=123456")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['login[camera_code]'] = '123456'
br.form['login[pass]'] = '7890'
br.submit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())
links = soup.find_all('img', src=True)

for link in links:
    timestamp = time.asctime()
    link = link["src"].split("src=")[-1]
    print link
```

But I got error as below, how can I avoid these errors, or is that any eaisr way to scrape web page with password? thanks a lot.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:181: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.
The code that caused this warning is on line 21 of the file login.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:
BeautifulSoup([your markup])
to this:
BeautifulSoup([your markup], "html.parser")
markup_type=markup_type))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error - just a mere warning. Since you did not specify the parser explicitly.

Modify this line -

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read(),"html.parser")
```

And see if it works out. Answering from mobile so code is not formatted. Will do it once I access my pc in an hour :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! then when I view some images on page http://ipcamera.userlocal.jp//photos/hours, but when I scraped it that I can't get links, do you know why?

Comment: @mikezang it redirects me to the login page, you should get a link in the html response

Comment: I think that image links is created by javascript, how can I easy to scrape such pages?

Comment: I'd/pw: 502241/7116 I want to scrape all images, can you help me? I can ask another question if you don't mind after I accept this answer:)

Comment: it seems to be genrating and fetching images from https://secure-api.userlocal.jp if you have access to this in some way there can be a way forward.

Comment: You mean it is impossible?

Comment: no but you would want access to the above url... the list of images that get stored in that server... can't really say more than this I guess

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got what I need  by WebDriver, Selenium and Phantom.